# Changing which main() to run in eclipse

Tags: java, game-engine

In Eclipse, how should I change the entry point for my program.
I have two separate packages each with static main methods. My original static main method found in the main package will now be called upon after running the main method found in the title package.

What I want to happen is:

Display the title screen, and If the user choice to play the game then call the Game.main()

Here are the two classes:

```
    package game.title;

import game.main.entities.movement.MenuKeyListener;
import game.main.graphics.ImageLoader;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.*;

import src.game.main.Game;

// Referenced classes of package game.main:
//            MenuKeyListener, Game

public class TitleScreen extends JFrame
{
    class MyCanvas extends Canvas
    {

        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
            super.paint(g);
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, TitleScreen.SCREENHEIGHT, TitleScreen.SCREENWIDTH, this);
        }

        public void update(Graphics g)
        {
            if(TitleScreen.toggle == 0)
            {
                g.clearRect(0, 0, TitleScreen.SCREENWIDTH, TitleScreen.SCREENHEIGHT);
                g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, TitleScreen.SCREENHEIGHT, TitleScreen.SCREENWIDTH, this);
                int xCord[] = {
                    322, 350, 350
                };
                int yCord[] = {
                    533, 533, 553
                };
                g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
                g.fillPolygon(xCord, yCord, 3);
            } else
            if(TitleScreen.toggle == 1)
            {
                g.clearRect(0, 0, TitleScreen.SCREENWIDTH, TitleScreen.SCREENHEIGHT);
                g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, TitleScreen.SCREENHEIGHT, TitleScreen.SCREENWIDTH, this);
                int xCord[] = {
                    322, 350, 350
                };
                int yCord[] = {
                    600, 600, 620
                };
                g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
                g.fillPolygon(xCord, yCord, 3);
            }
        }

        final TitleScreen this$0;

        MyCanvas()
        {
            this$0 = TitleScreen.this;
            //super();
        }
    }


    public static void main(String args[])
        throws IOException
    {
        new TitleScreen();
    }

    public TitleScreen()
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        SCALE = 2;
        quit = false;
        runGame = false;
        setTitle("Mortem");
        setSize(new Dimension(SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
        setResizable(false);
        MyCanvas canvas = new MyCanvas();
        add(canvas);
        ImageLoader loader = new ImageLoader();
        image = loader.load("/Title Screen.jpg");
        setVisible(true);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(20, 20));
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label.setLocation(10, 10);
        label.setSize(220, 100);
        panel.add(label);
        //Sound music = new Sound("/piano1.wav");
        //music.play();
        canvas.addKeyListener(new MenuKeyListener());
        while(!check) 
        {
            canvas.update(canvas.getGraphics());
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(500L);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if(toggle == 1){
            System.out.println("BYE!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else if(toggle == 0)
        {
            //music.stop();
            Game.main(null);
            System.out.println("Start Game!");

        }
    }

    private static int SCREENWIDTH = 700;
    private static int SCREENHEIGHT = 700;
    private int SCALE;
    private static Graphics g;
    private final BufferedImage image;
    private static BufferedImage titleImage;
    public static int toggle = 0;
    private boolean quit;
    private boolean runGame;
    public static boolean check = false;




}
```

Which calls:

```
    package game.main;

import game.main.entities.Enemy;
import game.main.entities.Entity;
import game.main.entities.Player;
import game.main.entities.Title;
import game.main.entities.movement.EnemyMovementThread;
import game.main.entities.movement.KeyManager;
import game.main.graphics.CharacterSpriteSheet;
import game.main.graphics.ImageLoader;
import game.main.graphics.ImageManager;
import game.main.graphics.SpriteSheet;
import game.main.levels.Level;
import game.main.sounds.Sound;
import game.main.tiles.Heart0Tile;
import game.main.tiles.Tile;
import game.title.TitleScreen;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable{

    public static final int HEIGHT = 240, WIDTH = 360,  SCALE = 3, TILESIZE = 16;
    public static boolean running = false;
    public Thread gameThread;
    public Thread enemyMovement;

    private BufferedImage spriteSheet;
    private BufferedImage characterAnimation;
    private static ImageManager im;
    private static Level level1;

    static BufferedImage level;


    private static Player player;
    private static Enemy enemy;
    private Title title;
    private Heart0Tile life;

    private Sound titleTheme;

    public void init() throws IOException{
        ImageLoader loader = new ImageLoader();
        spriteSheet = loader.load("/SS.png");
        characterAnimation = loader.load("/characterAnimation.png");

        SpriteSheet ss = new SpriteSheet(spriteSheet);
        CharacterSpriteSheet ca = new CharacterSpriteSheet(characterAnimation);
        im = new ImageManager(ss, ca);

        level = loader.load("/level1.png");

        level1 = new Level(level);



        player = new Player(WIDTH * SCALE / 2, HEIGHT * SCALE /2, im);
        enemy = new Enemy(WIDTH * SCALE /2, HEIGHT * SCALE /2 , im);

        this.addKeyListener(new KeyManager());

        title = new Title(50, 70, ss);

        titleTheme = new Sound("/Boss theme riff (1).wav");

        titleTheme.play();



    }

    public synchronized void start(){
        if(running)return;
            running = true;
            gameThread = new Thread(this);
            gameThread.start();
            enemyMovement = new Thread(new EnemyMovementThread("enemyMovement", 2000));
            enemyMovement.start();
        }

    public synchronized void stop(){
        if(running == false) return;
        running = false;
        try{
            gameThread.join();
            enemyMovement.join();
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void run(){
        try {
            init();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        final double AMOUNTOFTICKS = 60D;
        double ns = 1000000000/AMOUNTOFTICKS;
        double delta = 0;


        while(running){
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime)/ns;
            lastTime = now;
            if(delta >= 1){
                tick();
                delta--;
            }


            render();
        }
        stop();
    }

    public void tick(){
        player.tick();

        //enemy.tick();
        //title.tick();

    }

    public void render(){
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if(bs == null){
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }


        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

        //RENDER HERE
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH*SCALE, HEIGHT*SCALE);
        level1.render(g);
        //title.render(g);
        player.render(g);
        //enemy.render(g);

        //END RENDER
        g.dispose();
        bs.show();


    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
    Game game = new Game();
    game.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(WIDTH*SCALE, HEIGHT*SCALE));
    game.setMaximumSize( new Dimension(WIDTH*SCALE, HEIGHT*SCALE));
    game.setMinimumSize( new Dimension(WIDTH*SCALE, HEIGHT*SCALE));

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Game");
    frame.setSize(WIDTH*SCALE, HEIGHT*SCALE);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);//change later
    frame.add(game);

    frame.setVisible(true);
    game.start();
    }

    public static Player getPlayer(){
        return player;
    }
    public static Enemy getEnemy(){
        return enemy;
    }
    public static Level getLevel(){
        return level1;
    }
    public static ImageManager getImageManager(){
        return im;
    }

}
```

After try to run the TitleScreen class I get this in my console:

Error: Could not find or load main class game.title.TitleScreen

Answer (score 0):

In "Run Configuration" menu you can set your main class to be run.

Answer (score 0):

To change your main method, you need to modify it in your launch configurations.

```
1.Right click your project
2. Select Run as-> Run Configurations
3. Set your main method for your application by searching the main class.
4. Save configuration and run your project.
```